# Postgis - How to find best route for origin x destination

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I have a table which store "Routes" composed by a name and two geometry points (origin and destination). The user will inform his origin and his destination, and I should get the best route, which best matches his origin and destination point (or maybe a list of best routes, from best to worse). The path doesn't matter, just the origin and destination point.

I have created this query, which is adapted from a query to find the closest points to a point, but it sometimes gives me the correct result, but sometimes don't.

```
SELECT "Routes".Name AS name, origin.location AS origin, 
destination.location AS destination FROM "Routes"
JOIN "StopPoints" AS origin ON ("Routes"."originId" = origin.id)
JOIN "StopPoints" AS destination ON ("Routes"."destinationId" = 
destination.id)
ORDER BY origin.location <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-26.956636, 
-48.639537), 0),
destination.location <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-26.907525, -48.661486), 0);
```

The coordinates defined there are just for example. And ignore the use of "StopPoints", it's something that'll be implemented later. Consider that I have just one origin and one destination point, and I want to get the best route from a table which every row has an origin and destination point too.

Comment: I'm using now st_distance instead of the <-> operator and it seems to be fine, I'll continue testing and relate it later.

Answer (score 1):

The current query doesn't work because it is only optimizing the distance to the start point, and only if two routes have the same start point then the distance to the end point is considered.

A simplistic solution would be to consider the sum of the distances to the start and end points, and to find the routes having the smallest cumulative distance.

You can also optimize it a bit by only considering start/end points within X km of your location. Should you want to consider a network that is a bit more complex, routing solution such as pg_routing should be considered.

Here is your query modified to consider the sum of the distances to the start/end points

```
SELECT "Routes".Name AS name, origin.location AS origin, 
destination.location AS destination 
FROM "Routes"
  JOIN "StopPoints" AS origin ON ("Routes"."originId" = origin.id)
  JOIN "StopPoints" AS destination ON ("Routes"."destinationId" = 
destination.id)
ORDER BY origin.location <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-26.956636, 
-48.639537), 0) + destination.location <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-26.907525, -48.661486), 0);
```